# NSFileSize only returns 102

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion, nsfilemanager

When I call the following line of code, the returned value is always 102.

```
[[(NSFileManager*)manager attributesOfItemAtPath:[(NSURL*)file path] error:nil] objectForKey:@"NSFileSize"];
```

For the sake of demonstration, I'll NSLog the path and it's size.
[image]

Aperture (the path I ran through the code above) is actually 912MB.
[image: d]

What am I doing wrong here? I really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you cast `NSFileManager` and `NSURL`?

Comment: @mavrick3 I was doing that for demonstration. I don't do that in my code.

Comment: @Tanner_Silvia It was the first post I saw in this style, so I was just wondering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.app` *file* is actually a special folder called an [App Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html).  Folders (directories) only need to hold meta information for their content, so 102 bytes looks about right to me.

If you want the size of the binary then look at `Aperature.app/Contents/MacOS/Aperature`, although the 912.5MB shown probably includes **all** the files in the bundle, not just the binary.

Comment: But you probably want the size of all fles under the .app directory not just the executable

Answer (score 0):

`attributesOfItemAtPath` will not work for folder.